# C Structure like variables in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, concatenation, structure, unions

What I want to do is have Q - 10 bit & C - 4 bit and perform the operation -

`Q,C = Q,C << 1` (left shift MSB of C into LSB of Q)

Where Q,C is 14 bit treated like a structure in C. This is natively supported in verilog, can be achieved with structures in C. How do I do something similar in MATLAB?

Comment: Does the MSB of Q get lost during the operation or Q become 11 bits?

Comment: In the algorithm I am implementing, it becomes 11 bits, but I am okay if it is lost for now. I could always make it longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think matlab supports c style unions. It does have the `bitshift` function that enables you to solve this problem using arithmetic.

```
% Q is 10 bits, C is 4 bits
% Create QC. 
QC = bitshift(Q, 4) + C;  

% Bit shift QC by 1
QC = bitshift(QC,1);

%Grab QC bits 13->4 and save as Q
Q = bitshift(QC, -4);

%get QC bits 3->0 and save as C
C = bitand(QC, 2^(4+1)-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. This should get the job done. I guess my thoughts were boxed for the want of structures.